# how to change display name or nickname of ubuntu server? (AWS EC2)

Tags: 16.04, amazon-ec2, aws

I'm wondering how I can change the displaying name when I log into my server.

So for example I SSH into the server and it display my username @ ec2 instance ip.

```
example: username@ip-10.0.0.129

what I want: username@production
```

I don't want it to affect any DNS, host, hostname or Ip stuff only to give it a nickname, any suggestions?

another example:
When Cron finishes its job it sends an email from root

```
Cron <root@ip-10-0-0-129>.....

what I want: Cron <root@production>.....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to change is the `PS1` variable.
It is not an environment variable but a [bash shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931855/why-env-does-not-print-ps1-variable).
If you are interested in learning more about that [look here](https://linoxide.com/how-tos/change-bash-prompt-variable-ps1/).

To be brief, if you want to just change the part where traditionally you'll see the server name, just to the following:

1 In a terminal `echo $PS1`.
You will probably see something like:

`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$`

In it \u stands for Username and \h stands for Hostname.

2 Still in the terminal try doing:

`PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\What you want the hostname to be: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@What you want the hostname to be\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$"`

Notice the quotes that need to be added here but won't be in stage 3.

3 When you are satisfied with the results go to your .bashrc file and replace what it says in the line where PS1 is defined. Notice that it appears several times in the file and that each one should be changed differently and separately (ideally, at least).
Save and quit the file.

4 Type `. ~/.bashrc`, this should reload the file and start presenting the prompt you have set.
All we did currently will change it for your user. It will not change it for the root user.
To do that you must edit the file /root/.bashrc in a similar fashion.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @paul9494 ,welcome. Can I suggest that you edit the tags? If the is one for bashrc, or for the command prompt (or even terminal in general), they’re more relevant than ec2 or aws).

Comment: @paul9494 did this solve your issue?

Comment: Making these changes you suggested works while I'm logged in but on reboot it resets to the IP, I changed my /etc/hosts to: 
127.0.0.1 localhost production
and then change my /etc/hostname to: 
production
Do a reboot and now my terminal always has: username@production
BTW: so far I've not experienced any troubles changing these files, should I be worried?
Thank you!

Comment: @paul9494 did you save the .bashrc files?

Comment: Yes I saved them but for some reason it goes back to IP after reboot

Comment: I suspect you are conflating two issues.
I never recommended editing /etc/hostname or /etc/hosts.
If you want to change the host name use `hostnamectl` it's the modern way to do that.
If this is not what you mean then can you please expand the question with what you did and what occurs, and also the .bashrc file so I can troubleshoot this better?

Comment: Yes so I needed the terminal to be username@production at all times for whoever is SSH'd into my instance without having to invoke a function to change the displaying name.
We have multiple instances and Cron jobs running from each instance.
This instance is new and the other instances were already configured to display username@instanceName and since Cron logs are mailed to root@instanceName we want to make it clear from which instance it's performing the cron jobs (i.e. show username@production and make it clear that current terminal is production since people have maybe 3-5 different...

Comment: terminals open with different instances,
The modification of bashr you recommended "works" but users shouldn't have to invoke it everytime by typing in . ~/.bashrc.
I got access to one of the other instances and saw it was configured by changing /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts so I tried using the same configuration for my instance and it worked

Comment: So what you did is exactly changing the host name. Glad it worked!